# Firebase .length broken on infinate scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

my NextJs site keeps throwing error due to firebase infinate scroll. .length being undefinded for some unknown reaseon. please help debug the code if possible. Its been a mess trying to get this dmn stuff to work in nextjs.

```
useEffect(() => {
    
    // This useEffect is used to get the todos for the user
    try {
      if (!firestore) return;
      // Only execute the query if we have an user
      const querySubmissions = query(
            collection(firestore, "roadmap"),
            where("csite", "==", router.query.csite),
            where("uid", "==", router.query.uid),
            orderBy("createdAt", "desc"),
            limit(10)
          );
      if (!querySubmissions) return;
      const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(querySubmissions, (querySnapshot) => {
        setSubmissions(querySnapshot.docs);
      });
      return () => unsubscribe();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }, [router]);


// -------------------- unessesary code removed between -------------------------------------


  useEffect(() => {

  window.onscroll = () => {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
  console.log('bottom');
    setIsLoadingData(true);
    const lastDocument = submissions.data().length - 1;
    const documents = query(
      collection(firestore, "roadmap"),
      where("csite", "==", router.query.csite),
      where("uid", "==", router.query.uid),
      orderBy("createdAt", "desc"),
      limit(10),
      startAfter(lastDocument)
    );
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(documents, (querySnapshot) => {
      setSubmissions(submissions => submissions.concat(querySnapshot.docs));
      setIsLoadingData(false);
    });
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }
  };
  }, [router]);
```

Please help.

I was expecting infinate scroll when creating this code in VSCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that ive fixed the issue by replacing the code as below.

```
useEffect(() => {

  window.onscroll = () => {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
  console.log('bottom');
    setIsLoadingData(true);
    const lastDocument = submissions[submissions.length - 1];
    try {
      if (!firestore) return;
      // Only execute the query if we have an user
      const querySubmissions = query(
            collection(firestore, "roadmap"),
            where("csite", "==", router.query.csite),
            where("uid", "==", router.query.uid),
            orderBy("createdAt", "desc"),
            limit(10),
            startAfter(lastDocument)
          );
      if (!querySubmissions) return;
      const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(querySubmissions, (querySnapshot) => {
        setSubmissions(submissions => submissions.concat(querySnapshot.docs));
        setIsLoadingData(false);
      });
      return () => unsubscribe();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
  };
});
```